# Refresh table using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I store some user's data in cookies and then I append all data to the table:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/recent/",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
        var recent = JSON.parse(data['recent']).reverse();
        $('.container').append(get_table(recent));
    },
    error: function(d){
        alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
    }
  });
```

So my question might be a little bit stupid, but doesn't my table have to be refreshed every time I change data in cookies since I'm getting it using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it won't refresh everytime you change data in cookies. That's because you only append the first data you received and you saved in cookies.

If you want to refresh your table everytime you change data in cookies you will need to create a listener that tells you that the data has changed.